# Devise telling me "Email already taken" when I try to register my name and email.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm new to programming, and have been learning Ruby on Rails for about 12 weeks.

I have a devise users/sign_up page on my App now, and after entering my name and password, it tells me to check my email account for a confirmation message. The message never came, so I did some research and debugging, and I think the problem may be solved. HOWEVER, now I can't use the same email to try out my fix, because when I register again, I get "1 error prohibited this user from being saved: email already taken." (I did some research on this here on StackOverflow, but I think those answers may be too old - can't see what they are talking about in any of my devise files.)
Is there any way I can clear out the email so that I can enter register it again?

Comment: just delete it in your DB. run `rails console`, then `User.find_by(email: 'your_email').destroy`. I am making the assumption here that you are still running this app locally and you won't mind deleting anythings related to that user...their details or associations...

Comment: Thanks! I was using "find" instead of "find_by."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just delete the user in your Database.

first, connect to your database by running `rails console` in your Terminal.

Then, you can find and delete your user by running the query

```
User.find_by(email: 'foo@bar.com').destroy
```

This article is worth a read on Rails finder methods. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html